# Reverse tether to Windows 8.1

Tags: internet-sharing

I have a Lumia 920 running Denim and am curious if there's any way to reverse tether it to a desktop PC through a USB connection (by reverse tether, I mean using the internet connection supplied to the desktop on the phone).

The reason for this is essentially I don't have data on my mobile plan, I normally just use whatever WiFi network I can get access to, but because of a temporary office move, there's no open WiFi available, so I was wondering if I could hook my phone up to my computer to use things like WhatsApp.

I've had a search around and can find a few places talking about doing this with an Android phone, or it being possible using the Zune program (I think) on Windows 7, but nothing about doing it on the hardware / software I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though Windows 8.1 does provide USB option if you search for it but the settings there are related to only your storage settings. And hence Windows 8.1 still doesnt have tethering enabled.
Its a feature thats been requested a lot and is needed but still not available :(